# Multiple different data types in a Node for a custom linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to build a linked list, and each node will have one integer, which is node's position, and a string which is node's name.

```
public class Node {

    public int position;
    public Node next;
    public String shipname;

    public Node(int num, String shipname) {
        position = num;
        shipname = shipname;
    }

    public void insert(int x, String shipname) {
        Node newNode = new Node(num, shipname);
        Node previous = null;
        Node current = first;

        while (current != null && num < current.position) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        if (previous == null) {
            newNode.next = first;
            first = newNode;
        } else {
            previous.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = current;
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        Node current = first;

        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.shipname + " " + current.position);
            current = current.next;
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
    }

}
```

Is there any reason, why this code gives position data correctly, but "null" instead of writing shipnames to the screen? Here is a simple output:

```
Largest priority to Smallest
null 7
null 4
null 3
```

Comment: Try doing `this.position` and `this.shipname` in the constructor on the lhs of the assignment.

Comment: Where is 'first' defined

Comment: What is `num` inside the insert function?

Comment: I am even surprised that the first line the insert method does not throw a compilation error.

Comment: Try doing this.position and this.shipname in the constructor on the lhs of the assignment. – 0x499602D2 3 mins ago

this solved my problem, thank you 0x499602D2

Comment: Please don't edit your question with "solved".  If an answer has helped you, you may accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.  If you have an answer for yourself, you may answer your question and accept it a day later.

Comment: wow I came back to my question after 3 years, and have no clue at all what I was trying to ask here :) you guys are awesome

Answer (score 1):

It seems you wanna a code like this.

```html
public class LinkedListA<T> {
 static class Node<T>{
  T data;
  Node<T> next;
  public Node(T d){
   this.data=d;
   this.next=null;
  }
  
 }
 
 Node<T> head;
 public LinkedListA(){
  head=null;
 }
 public void add(T v) {
  Node<T> new_node=new Node<T>(v);
  if(this.head==null) {
   this.head=new_node;
  }else {
   Node<T> current_node=this.head;
   while(current_node.next!=null) {
    current_node=current_node.next;
   }
   current_node.next=new_node;
  }
  
 }
 public void addLast(T v) {
  add(v);
 }
 public void print() {
  Node<T> current_node=this.head;
  while(current_node!=null) {
   
   System.out.println(current_node.data);
   current_node=current_node.next;
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  LinkedListA<Integer> list=new LinkedListA<Integer>();
  list.add(10);
  list.add(20);
  list.add(30);
  list.addLast(40);
  System.out.println("===LIST=====");
  list.print();

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some errors. For example, Node is a node and not a list. A list is made up of multiple nodes. So outer class should be a list and it should contain nodes...

Here is my code for a Singly Linked list:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Template
{
    public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        SingleLinkedList<Integer> list = new SingleLinkedList<Integer>();
        list.add(in.nextInt());
        list.add(in.nextInt());
        list.add(in.nextInt());
        list.add(in.nextInt());
        list.add(in.nextInt());
        list.print();

        list.reverse();
        list.print();
    }
}

class SingleLinkedList<Item>
{
    private class Node
    {
        private Item data;
        private Node next;

        public Node(Item data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }

        public void setData(Item data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Item getData()
        {
            return this.data;
        }

        public Node getNext()
        {
            return this.next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    private int size;
    private Node head;

    public SingleLinkedList()
    {
        size = 0;
        head = new Node(null);
    }

    //Add at end
    public void add(Item data)
    {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;

        while(current.getNext() != null)
        {
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        current.setNext(node);
        size++;
    }

    //Add at a specific index (Node after head = index 1)
    public void add(Item data, int index)
    {
        int i=0;
        Node current = head;
        Node node = new Node(data);
        while(i<index-1 && current.getNext() != null)
        {
            current = current.getNext();
            i++;
        }

        if(index - i == 1)
        {
            node.setNext(current.getNext());
            current.setNext(node);
            size++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid index");
            return;
        }
    }

    //Print linked list
    public void print()
    {
        Node current = head.getNext();

        String output = "[head] -> ";
        while(current != null)
        {
            output += "["+current.getData().toString()+"] -> ";
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        output+="[null]";
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    //Remove node at an index (1 based)
    public void remove(int index)
    {
        int i=0;
        Node current = head;

        if(index < 1 || index > size)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Index");
            return;
        }

        while(i<index-1 && current.getNext() != null)
        {
            current = current.getNext();
            i++;
        }

        current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
        size--;
    }

    //Reverse the linked list
    public void reverse()
    {
        Node current = head.getNext();
        Node prevNode = null;
        Node nextNode;
        if(size < 2)
        {
            return;
        }

        while(current != null)
        {
            nextNode = current.getNext();
            current.setNext(prevNode);
            prevNode = current;
            current = nextNode;
        }
        head.setNext(prevNode);
    }
}
```

Notice that I am declaring and using nodes inside the list class.

Answer (score 0):

Editing constructor with "this.shipname" and "this.position" solved my problem. Thank you all for your help

```
public Node(int num, String shipname) {
        this.position = num;
        this.shipname = shipname;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are referencing same local variable in your constructor.

```
public Node(int num, String shipname) {
    position = num;
    shipname = shipname;
}
```

Change this to assign,

```
this.shipname = shipname;
```

So the final code becomes :

```
public Node(int num, String shipname) {
    position = num;
    this.shipname = shipname;
}
```

There seems to be another problem you have not declared variable 'first'.
Change variable 'x' to 'num' in 'insert' method.

And Java provides LinkedList class, you can take a look into that. I hvae updated your code using Java's LinkedList. Hope it helps.

```
public class NodeLinkedList {
    private class Node {
        int position;
        String shipName;

        Node(int position, String shipName) {
             this.position = position;
             this.shipName = shipName;
        }
    }

    private LinkedList<Node> nodeList;

    NodeLinkedList() {
        nodeList = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    void insert(int position, String name) {
         nodeList.add(new Node(position, name));
    }

    void display(){
        for (Node node : nodeList) {
            System.out.println(node.shipName + " " + node.position);
        }
    }
}
```